# Making a crawler using Beautiful Soup, issues with indexing urls

Tags: python, indexing, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

So I am attempting to make a crawler for a search engine. I have the code mostly complete. The way it works is:

- to open the page using BeautifulSoup,
- save the url and a docID to an index (in this case just a text file),
- get some clean text and save it to a text file,
- get all urls off the page, and add them to the list of pages if it isn't already in the index.

The issue I'm having is that sometimes, it will index urls multiple times.

An example run I did was with the initial `pages = ["http://www.ece.udel.edu"]`. In the output file, each line contains a docID and a url. The format of this is `docID url\n`. This will cause issue when ranking the results because, while it should rank these result the same, I will have multiple of the same page (each with a different docID) being ranked.

Here is the code I have so far. I attempted to thoroughly comment it to make it easier to understand.

```
def cleanText(soup):
    #remove all unnecessary tags & punctuation leaving text of all lowercase letters & words
    texts = soup.findAll(text=True)
    visible_elements=[]
    for elem in texts:
        if elem.parent.name in ['style', 'script', '[document]', 'head', 'title']:
            visible_elements.append('')
        elem = elem.encode('utf-8','replace')
        result = re.sub('<!--.*-->|\r|\n', '', str(elem), flags=re.DOTALL)
        result = re.sub('\s{2,}|&nbsp;', ' ', result)
        visible_elements.append(result)
    visible_text = ' '.join(visible_elements)
    visible_text = re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', ' ', visible_text)
    visible_text = visible_text.lower()
    return visible_text

def naming(pagename, pathToOutput):
    #used to create filename to save output text file
    cantBeInFilename = ("/", "\\",":","*","?","<",">","|")
    for k in range(len(cantBeInFilename)):
        pagename = pagename.replace(cantBeInFilename[k], "-")
    filename = "\\".join((pathToOutput, pagename))
    filename = ".".join((filename, "txt"))
    return filename

def crawl(pages, pathToOutput, pathToLinks):
    depth = len(pages)
    docID = 1
    for i in range(depth): #for each link on the page
        newpages=set() #create an empty set for gathered pages
        for page in pages: #each page in pages, initially atleast 1
            linksText = open(pathToLinks, 'a') #open a file
            linksText.write(str(docID) + " "); #write a docID to identify page
            docID = docID + 1 #increment docID
            linksText.write(str(page) + '\n') #append link into end of file
            linksText.close() #close file to update
            try:
                c = urllib2.urlopen(page) #open the page
                print ("Opening " + page)
            except:
                print ("Could not open " + page)
                continue
            soup = BeautifulSoup(c.read())
            clean_text = cleanText(soup)
            #get all links off page
            links = soup.findAll('a')
            #write web page to text file in pathToOutput directory
            filename = naming(page, pathToOutput)
            f = open(filename, 'w')
            f.write(clean_text)
            f.close()
            depth = 0
            for link in links:
                if('href' in dict(link.attrs)):
                    #set depth equal to the # of links in the pages
                    depth = depth+1
                    url = urljoin(page, link['href'])
                    #remove unnecessary portions of url
                    if url.find("'") != -1:
                        continue
                    url = url.split('#')[0]
                    #get each line (each link) from linksText
                    linksText = open(pathToLinks, 'r')
                    lines = linksText.readlines()
                    linksText.close()
                    #remove docIDs just to have 
                    for j in range(len(lines)):
                        lines[j-1] = lines[j-1].split()[1]
                    #FOR ALL LINKS
                    if url[0:4] == "http":
                        #check to see if the url ends with a /, if so remove it
                        if url[len(url)-1]=="/":
                            url = url[0:len(url)-1]
                        #check to see if the url is already in links
                        present = 0
                        for line in lines:
                            if (url == line):
                                present = 1
                            else:
                                present = 0
                        #if the url isn't present, add to pages to be cycled through
                        if (present == 0):
                            print ("Indexing " + url)
                            newpages.add(url)
                #add newpages to pages
                for newpage in newpages:
                    pages.append(newpage)
                newpages = set()
            #remove already read page from pages
            pages.remove(page)
```

I would attach the output I have already gotten from this but I just started on the site and can't post a question with more than two links :( Sorry if this is long, confusing, and just plain doesn't make sense

Comment: Your code would be much easier to read and you'd get more responses if you 'pythonified' it. Start by changing all the `x[len(x)-y]` into simply `len[-y]`. Then change the file IO to equivalent `with` statements. (See the end of section 7.2.1 [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)).

Comment: Also try to pare down your code to essentials. You don't have to show the `clean_text` and `naming` functions or its call in your code. Remove the entire `# write web page to text file in pathToOutput directory` block in fact.

Comment: `soup.findAll` should be `soup.find_all`. And use [a proper filter](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-the-tree) instead of your conditional in the loop

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet isn't doing what you think

```
present = 0
for line in lines:
    if (url == line):
        present = 1
    else:
        present = 0
#if the url isn't present, add to pages to be cycled through
if (present == 0):
    print ("Indexing " + url)
    newpages.add(url)
```

This will only leave `present = 1` if the match is on the very last item of the string. A simpler way to test it would be:

```
#if the url isn't present, add to pages to be cycled through
if url not in lines:
    print ("Indexing " + url)
    newpages.add(url)
```

You may also have to change

```
#get each line (each link) from linksText
linksText = open(pathToLinks, 'r')
lines = linksText.readlines()
linksText.close()
```

into

```
#get each line (each link) from linksText
linksText = open(pathToLinks, 'r')
lines = linksText.read().split('\n')
linksText.close()
```

so that each `line` in `lines` doesn't end with `\n`

Comment: I changed the two things you suggested. For the first one, it doesn't seem to be fixing the issue. I re-ran after changing the few lines and still received duplicate links with different docIDs. As for the second suggestion, I don't think its neccesary because of the line below that says for j in range(len(lines)): lines[j] = lines[j].split()[1] and when it splits each line it removes the \n at the end. Thank you though :) @Felipe